# Анонимный чат бот(серверная часть) Python

Tags: python, логика

Думаю над тем, как реализовать анонимного чат-бота для паблика вконтакте.
Как лучше реализовать серверную часть?
Первый пользователь пишет "go", ему отправляется сообщение о том, что поиск начался, как только появляется ещё один пользователь написавший 'go' им обоим пишется о том, что собеседник найден и их сообщения пересылаются друг другу. Суть вопроса вот в чём, каким методом лучше реализовать подбор, так чтобы багов не было и оптимизация была хорошая, в мыслях только через массив с пользователями и бесконечным while циклом.

Comment: Есть исходники вашего бота? если есть можете поделиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда пользователь пишет 'go', его ВК ID добавляется в 'некий' приватный список, потом сервер каждые 5-10 секунд выбирает два первых ID с этого списка.(Сервер должен выбрать только два ID с списка за раз.)

Comment: Примерно так же реализовал, пока что всё хорошо работает, на большой нагрузке не тестировал